# 3D map using leaflet

Tags: javascript, visualization

I'm trying to create 3D bars on this map. Can anyone please advise if this is possible, and how?

http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

My data: UFO sightings in the USA (location wise).
Count of these sightings per location will be the height of the 3D bar.
Base map is a choropleth with US population density values.

I don't mind integrating Javascript or d3.js into the code to create the 3D bars.

Comment: how did you solved this one? i am trying create 3d using d3 and topjson.

Comment: @DadhichiTripathi, Sorry. I couldn't create the 3D bars on the map at that point. It was a school project and I was running out of time, so  I ended up using circle markers instead. Sorry, I couldn't be of much help here.